# Can I get a save for PS3 that alters Mass Effect 1 decisions?

Tags: mass-effect-3, ps3, mass-effect

As I can't seem to find Mass Effect 1 on PS3 and have been informed that it was made for 360 only, is there any way to get a save for PS3 to make the changes in ME3 based on decisions made in it, or do I just have to miss it and forget about it and just play ME3 with the save I have for Mass Effect 2?

And if it is possible to get ME1 decision save for the PS3 can anybody tell me where and how it needs to be done? And how much of an impact it will actually have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there was no release of Mass Effect for the PS3, Bioware released an [interactive comic](http://www.joystiq.com/2010/12/17/mass-effect-2s-ps3-exclusive-comic-how-it-works/) as DLC, which allows you to make some of the decisions from ME1 that impact the ME2 (and ME3) story.  They later made this available on other platforms.

The only downside to this is that you'll have to have downloaded, installed, and used this DLC prior to starting your run on ME2 - otherwise, you're starting from the "default" no-save-imported state in ME2, and those default choices will carry over into ME3.