# Can I customize Mass Effect 2's galaxy status without a Mass Effect 1 save file?

Tags: mass-effect-2, mass-effect

I played Mass Effect 1 and deleted the saved data and now I want to play the second game but I don't want to play with the default choices. Is there anything I can do to edit those default choices?

Comment: What system are you playing on? I'd bet we might have a save creator for PC, but consoles might not be as easy.

Comment: Also, for consoles I would suspect this goes against their terms and conditions

Comment: Depending on the platform, this might be a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55358/can-i-get-a-save-for-ps3-that-alters-mass-effect-1-decisions. In any case, it seems that there's a DLC for ME1 that allows you to generate a save file that is available on other platforms. Obviously there are sites that have saves for the PC.

Comment: @ DJ pirtu- its pc

Comment: Can anyone suggest some website providing saved games of ME 1?

Answer (score 2):

When you start a new game in Mass Effect 2 without importing a save file from Mass Effect 1, a variety of default options are chosen to choices that could be made in Mass Effect 1. There is no way to change these choices in Mass Effect 2 however, it is possible to create a Mass Effect 2 save and then use an external editor to change the default choices.

In order to do this you will need to do the following:

1. Start a new game and create a new character (don't import)
2. Play through the introduction level and the initial cutscenes until you "wake up" and are able to save your game. Save and exit the game
3. Download and open [Gibbed's Mass Effect 2 Save Editor](http://mod.gib.me/masseffect2/saveedit_rev25.zip)
4. Open the save file that you just created
5. Under the "Player" tab within the "Plot" tab - tick the "Played Mass Effect 1" option
6. Go to the "Plot" tab to change any of the other options you want
7. Ensure that "End Game State" under the "Plot" section on the "Raw" tab is set to an option that is *not* "NotFinished" (ie: "LivedToFightAgain" or "OutInABlazeOfGlory")
8. Save the edited file ensuring you stick with Mass Effect 2's naming convention (Autosave.pcsav, Quicksave.pcsav, Save_000#.pcsav, etc)
9. Open Mass Effect 2, start a new game and select Import Mass Effect 2 Character, choose the file you saved and play...

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: No

Long answer: Still no, but you could to get access to Mass Effect 1 save file and modifying it to get galaxy with choices you want. However, there is no way to adjust the galaxy in the game without a save file. It will always default to certain options.

Comment: I have a friend for a saved game file but we played it differently,taken diff decisions...Anything possible?